# How to use browser notification

Tags: push-notification

I am new in adding browser notification.How to use browser notification ? I couldn't figure out where to start. Can anyone provide me suggestion about how to start this.

Answer (score 0):

For the browser notification to work your site or application should be served over https otherwise browsers wont allow it

```
mesg = {
   title: "notification title",
   body: "notification body",
   icon: "location to an .ico image",
   timer: true //for auto closing
}

 // Let's check if the browser supports notifications
    if (!('Notification' in window)) {

      console.log('Browser does not support this feature.');

    }else if (Notification.permission === 'granted') {

      Notification.requireInteraction = false;

      if (mesg.title !== 'undefined') {

        const notification = new Notification(mesg.title, {
          body: mesg.body,
          icon: mesg.icon
        });

        if (mesg.timer) {

          setTimeout(function () {
            notification.close();
          }, 5000);
        }

        return notification;

      }// close if undefined

    } else if (Notification.permission !== 'denied') {

      alert('Please click Allow for enabling browser notifications');

      Notification.requestPermission(function (permission) {
        // If the user accepts, let's create a notification
        if (permission === 'granted') {

          if (mesg.title !== 'undefined') {

              const notification = new Notification(mesg.title, {
                body: mesg.body,
                icon: mesg.icon
              });

              if (mesg.timer) {
                setTimeout(function () {
                  notification.close();
                }, 5000);
              }

              return notification;

            }// close if undefined

          } else {

            alert('Permission Denied :[');

          }
        });
      }
```

I use this for my application, you can refactor it to remove duplicate code.

Answer (score 0):

Check [Notification API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/notification) for references

Code To request permission

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
        if (!Notification) {
            alert('Desktop notifications not available in your browser. Try Chromium.');
            return;
        }

        if (Notification.permission !== "granted")
            Notification.requestPermission();
    });
```

and for showing notifications

```
     if (Notification.permission !== "granted")
                    Notification.requestPermission();
                else {
                    var notification = new Notification('Notification title', {
                        icon: 'Icon Link',
                        body: "Notification Body",
                    });

                    notification.onclick = function () {
                        window.open("Href Here");
                    };

                }
```

Answer (score 0):

example

```
function notifyMe() {
  // Let's check if the browser supports notifications
  if (!("Notification" in window)) {
    alert("This browser does not support desktop notification");
  }

  // Let's check whether notification permissions have already been granted
  else if (Notification.permission === "granted") {
    // If it's okay let's create a notification
    var notification = new Notification("Hi there!");
  }

  // Otherwise, we need to ask the user for permission
  else if (Notification.permission !== "denied") {
    Notification.requestPermission(function (permission) {
      // If the user accepts, let's create a notification
      if (permission === "granted") {
        var notification = new Notification("Hi there!");
      }
    });
  }

  // At last, if the user has denied notifications, and you 
  // want to be respectful there is no need to bother them any more.
}
notifyMe();
```

more info https://developer.mozilla.org/id/docs/Web/API/notification